# detect connectivity issue or login failure of ImapMailReceiver

Tags: spring-integration, jakarta-mail

Using Spring integration with Spring mail to connect to IMAP inbox and read emails, I need to detect login failure and network connectivity issues, i cannot find any methods that would let me pull connection status, even errorChannel is not getting any messages nor the logs shows any network connectivity problems

```
 @Bean(name = "getImapMailReceiver")
    @Scope(scopeName = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    ImapMailReceiver getImapMailReceiver(Properties imapConnectionProperties) {
        ImapMailReceiver obj = new ImapMailReceiver(imapConnectionProperties.getProperty(IMAP_MAIL_URL_KEY));

        obj.setMaxFetchSize(Integer.parseInt(imapConnectionProperties.getProperty(IMAP_MAX_FETCH_SIZE_KEY)));
        obj.setJavaMailProperties(imapConnectionProperties);
        obj.setShouldDeleteMessages(false);
        obj.setAutoCloseFolder(false);
        obj.setShouldMarkMessagesAsRead(true);
        obj.setSimpleContent(false);
        obj.setCancelIdleInterval(10000);
        obj.setJavaMailAuthenticator(new Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(imapConnectionProperties.getProperty("mail.imap.user"),
                        imapConnectionProperties.getProperty("testpassword"));
            }
        });
        return obj;
    }
```

Comment: You probably need to share more config where you use this receiver. For example `MailReceivingMessageSource` does this `throw new MessagingException("failure occurred while polling for mail", e);`, which will go in the end to the error channel. The `ImapIdleChannelAdapter` emits this `ImapIdleExceptionEvent` in case of error on the `mailReceiver.receive()`.

Comment: @ArtemBilan turns out i need to use an ApllicationListener on the ImapIdleExceptionEvent, i will try it and update what happens.

Comment: @ArtemBilan added the event listener and i can extract the Thorwable messages and get the store state that way, i missed this part in the documentation, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To catch exceptions from such an `ImapIdleChannelAdapter` async component, you need to add a even listener for the `ImapIdleExceptionEvent`.

See more info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/mail.html#imap-idle-and-lost-connections